# how to display a regex result in flutter

Tags: regex, flutter

I try to display variable of the regex result into widget text in flutter

currently I have this input :

```
  var input = "Date:X/X/XX"              //Here is my input variable
   "Time:XX:XX:XX"
   "Speed:Xkm/h"
   "Altitude:XX.Xm"
   "Bat:XX%"
   "maps:google.com/maps?q=14.215465,-1.256584";
```

I have the regex code to extract longitude and latitude

```
     RegExp regExp = new RegExp(            //Here is the regex fonction to extract long, lat
     r"maps:google\.com\/maps\?q=(-?[0-9]+.[0-9]+),(-?[0-9]+.[0-9]+)",
    );
```

And my goal is to display long and lat variable ( after click ) like that

```
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return new Scaffold(
appBar: new AppBar(
 ),
 body: new Center(
 child: new Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
  new Text(

  $group1,$group2         //I want to display each variables extracted by regex

   ),
  ],
 ),
),
  floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: test,
  child: new Icon(Icons.add),
  ),
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: The regex should be defined as `r"maps:google\.com/maps\?q=(-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+),(-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)"` - dots should be escaped and `/` should not. What is the problem?

Comment: yes actually the regex code is ok https://regex101.com/r/5JVdgR/1 but I dont know how to display the result on a text widget in flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where you get the `input` from.
If you have it available when the widget is created, you can use

```
String $group1;
String $group2;

@override
void initState() {
  var match = regExp.firstMatch(input);
  $group1 = match.group(1);
  $group2 = match.group(2);
  super.initState();
}
```