# How to convert to double

Tags: dart, flutter

I validate the fonction of extract gps latitude and longitude with regex, but currently it's a String , and map_view accept only double

previous problem :
[how to display a regex result in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50756977/how-to-display-a-regex-result-in-flutter/50757158#50757158)

I tried to use this to convert in double but it doesn't work

```
    RegExp regExp = new RegExp(            //Here is the regex fonction to extract long, lat
       r"maps:google\.com\/maps\?q=(-?[0-9]+.[0-9]+),(-?[0-9]+.[0-9]+)",
      );
      var match = regExp.firstMatch(input);
      group1 = match.group(1);   //match groupe seems to be an int
      group2 = match.group(2);

      var long2 = double.parse('$group1');
      assert(long2 is double);
      var lat2 = double.parse('$group2');
      assert(lat2 is double);
```

Comment: What exactly does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: It is not related to regex. Tag removed.

Answer (score 111):

Remove the quotes from

```
 var long2 = double.parse('$group1');
```

to

```
 var long2 = double.parse($group1);
```

You can also use

```
var long2 = double.tryParse($group1);
```

or to also accept numbers without fractions

```
var long2 = num.tryParse($group1)?.toDouble();
```

to not get an exception when the string in `$group1` can not be converted to a valid double.

Comment: I modified but no result, group1 is ok and is display but when I try to convert with var long2 = double.tryParse($group1); I can't display ( return null)

Comment: What's the value of `$group1`? Just add a `print('group1 ${$group1}');` before the `tryParse()` line. And please try to avoid `$` in variable names.

Comment: I/flutter (12954): group1 14.215465

Comment: Perhaps you should use `num.tryParse($group1)?.toDouble()` to cover integer values as well.

Comment: Interpreted your log output wrong. No need to use `num.tryParsse()`. `double.tryParse()` works well for values without fractions. Try to reproduce the problem in https://dartpad.dartlang.org/

Comment: The widget text  didn't see correctly the double I use sharedpreference package to save Double and used it on my widget. it's OK right now :) thank you for the help and quick reply

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer You normally post great answers, but this one doesn't make any sense, despite being so highly upvoted(?!).  There is no variable named `$group1`.  If you meant `group1` and if `group1` is a `String?`, then there is no difference between `'$group1'` and `group1` except when it's `null`.

Comment: @jamesdlin you are right, this seems odd, but I guess this comes from the question (linked to in the above question "previous problem") that I answeres a bit earlier. It's a long time ago so I don't remember exactly.

Answer (score 5):

Why not use just group1 as in double.parse(group1)

Comment: Good catch :D It's confusing because in the linked question he uses `$group1` as variable name.