# Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid double

Tags: string, flutter, dart, parsing, double

I came across an error which is :

```
E/flutter ( 6195): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid double
E/flutter ( 6195): "41.16568"
E/flutter ( 6195): #0      double.parse (dart:core-patch/double_patch.dart:111:28)
E/flutter ( 6195): #1      _GuessTheLocationState.build.respon.<anonymous closure> (package:geoguess/main.dart:1175:34)
E/flutter ( 6195): #2      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1121:30)
E/flutter ( 6195): #3      _GuessTheLocationState.build.respon (package:geoguess/main.dart:1174:11)
E/flutter ( 6195): <asynchronous suspension>
```

I have no idea why it does not work. Code:

```
//sort 5 is String that is filled with random double. Example : "3.141"
//lattDouble is double

lattDouble = double.parse(sort5);
```

Comment: The string you're trying to parse has literal double-quote characters in it.  That is, you're calling `double.parse('"41.16568"')` instead of `double.parse("41.16568")` or `double.parse('41.16568')`.  You'll have to remove the quotes.

Comment: thanks for help but im not sure if is it possible to remove quote from string

Comment: You can't do `lattDouble = double.parse(sort5.substring(1, sort5.length - 1));`?

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50758704/how-to-convert-to-double

Comment: @Yashraj That is not related to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string you are are trying to convert has quotation marks in it. This leads to `double.parse()` failing. Before the conversion, you will have to remove these quotation marks.

```
var text = '"41.16568"';
text = text.replaceAll('"', '');
var number = double.parse(text);
```

If you know your string will always be in this format, you can alternatively remove first and last character of the string as discussed in the comments:

```
var text = '"41.16568"';
text = text.substring(1, text.length-1);
var number = double.parse(text);
```